# characterisation of compactness in the space of all convergent sequences

Tags: general-topology, sequences-and-series, analysis, functional-analysis, compactness

I go through a proof of the following.

Let $(\ell_1,d)$ be the metric space of all sequences $x = (\xi_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ with $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} |\xi_i| < \infty$ and the metric
$$
  d(x,y) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} |\xi_i - \eta_i|, \qquad x = (\xi_i), y = (\eta_i).
$$

> **Theorem**: A subset $M$ of $l_1$ is totally bounded (pre-compact) iff
>
> (i) There is a $K > 0$ with $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} |\xi_i| \le K$ for all $x = (\xi_i) \in M$;
>
> (ii) $\forall \varepsilon > 0 \exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N} \forall x = (\xi_i) \in M: \sum_{i=n_0}^{\infty} |\xi_i| < \varepsilon$.

The proof goes like this, let $M$ be a subset such that (i) and (ii) hold and let $x = (x_i)$ be a sequences in $\ell_1$ (i.e. a sequence of sequences), we show that it has a sub-sequence $x' = (x'_i)$ with $x'_i = (\xi^{(i)}_j)$ which is a Cauchy-Sequence. So let $\varepsilon > 0$ be given, then select $n_0$ such as in (ii), then
for $n,m > n_0$
\begin{align*}
 d(x_n, x_m) &= \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} | \xi^{(n)}_i - \xi^{(m)}_j | 
              \le \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} | \xi^{(n)}_i | - | \xi^{(m)}_j |
             \le 2\varepsilon
\end{align*}
(end of proof)

I dont understand the last steps, why is this sum smaller than $2\varepsilon$?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix $N$ which works for $\varepsilon/2$: this gives $\sum_{i\geq N}|\xi_i^{(n)}-\xi_i^{(m)}|\leq \varepsilon$. Then use the fact that the sequence of real numbers $\{\xi_k^{(m)}\}_m$ are Cauchy (up to a subsequence) for each $1\leq k\leq N-1$: this gives for each $k$, $N_k$ such that $|\xi_k^{(m)}-\xi_k^{(n)}|\leq \frac\varepsilon{2N}$. Then take $n_0:=\max\{N,\max_{1\leq k\leq N-1}N_k\}$.

For the other direction, we take $\varepsilon>0$, and $n_0$ in (ii) which works for $\varepsilon/2$. Then we use pre-compactness of $[-K,K]^{n_0}$ to get pre-compactness of $M$.

Comment: thanks, btw is the other direction trivial or why is it not mentioned in the proof?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the correct thing is
\begin{eqnarray}
 d(x_n, x_m) &=& \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} | \xi^{(n)}_i - \xi^{(m)}_j | \\
              &\le &\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} | \xi^{(n)}_i | + | \xi^{(m)}_j |\\
              &=& \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} | \xi^{(n)}_i | + \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} | \xi^{(m)}_j | \\
              &\le& \varepsilon + \varepsilon . \\
             &\le& 2\varepsilon
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 0):

Is it really just the last step that is at issue? As written in the OP, the argument the "proof" of the characterisation of totally boundedness in $\ell_1$ seems not just incomplete but also potentially muddled. If $(x_n)$ is a sequence in $\ell_1$, then we have, for each term $x_n \in \ell_1$ of the sequence $x_n = (\xi^{(n)}_i)_{i \geq 1}$, so noting that the norms of the tails of terms of the sequence are small does not, at least to me, immediately imply that it has a Cauchy subsequence.

The "obvious" way to prove that if $M\subseteq \ell_1$ is a subset with

1. $\|x\|_1<K$ for all $x \in M$ and,
2. for any $\epsilon>0$, there is an $n_0$ such that if $x= (\xi_i) \in M$ then $\sum_{k=n_0}^\infty |\xi_j|<\epsilon$.

then $M$ is totally bounded, would seem to me to be as follows:

We must show that, given $\epsilon>0$, there are $p_1,\ldots,p_N \in M$ such that $M \subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^N B(p_i,\epsilon)$. To show this for a give $\epsilon>0$, first note that by using $2)$, we may find an $n_0$ such that, for all $x= (\xi_i)_{i\geq 1} \in \ell_1$, we have $\sum_{i\geq n_0} |\xi_i|<\epsilon/4$. But now let $\pi\colon \ell_1 \to \mathbb R^{n_0-1}$ be the projection map sending $x=(\xi_i)_{i\geq 1}$ to $(\xi_1,\ldots,\xi_{n_0-1})$. Note that $\pi(M) \subseteq B(0,K)$ where we equip $\mathbb R^{n_0-1}$ with the $\|.\|_1$-norm. Now $\pi(M)$ is a bounded subset of $\mathbb R^{n_0-1}$, hence it is totally bounded, and so we may find $\{q_1,\ldots,q_N\}\subseteq \pi(M)$ such that $\pi(M) \subseteq \bigcup_{j=1}^N B(q_j,\epsilon/4)$.

Pick points $p_i \in M$ such that $\pi(p_i) = q_i$. Then we claim that $M \subseteq \bigcup_{j=1}^N B(p_i,\epsilon)$. Indeed if $x \in M$ then $\pi(x) \in B(q_{j_0},\epsilon/4)$ for some $j_0$, by the definition of the set $\{q_1,\ldots,q_N\}$. But then
$$
\begin{split}
\|p_{j_0}-x\|_1 &= \|q_{j_0}-\pi(x)\|_1 + \sum_{k\geq n_0}|p^i_k-\xi_k|\\
&=\|q_{j_0}-\pi(x)\|_1 + \sum_{k\geq n_0} |p^i_k|+|\xi_k| \\
&< \epsilon/4 + \epsilon/4 + \epsilon/4 = 3\epsilon/4 < \epsilon
\end{split}
$$

Thus $M$ is totally bounded as required.

To show that a Cauchy sequence in $M$ has a convergent subsequence seems to me to be harder (in that I don't see how to significantly short-cut the "standard argument" which would combine the above with the proof that any sequence in a totally bounded space has a Cauchy subsequence).