# A necessary and sufficient condition for $B \subset \ell^1$ to be compact

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I want to show that:

> For any $B\subset \ell^1$,
>   $B$ is compact **if and only if** $B$ is bounded, closed and satisfies
>   $$
> \forall \epsilon>0, \; \exists N\in \mathbb{N}, \; \forall \{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty \in B, \; \sum_{n=N}^\infty |x_n| < \epsilon.
> $$

Comment: So what is preventing you from your goal? You should share some thoughts or ideas you have on this. Otherwise it looks like you're just dumping homework here in the hope that some good soul will give you everything you want without your doing a thing.

Comment: Potentially related / useful: [1](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/216493/characterisation-of-compactness-in-the-space-of-all-convergent-sequences?rq=1), [2](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/438068/closed-set-in-l1-space), [3](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/267563/closed-set-in-ell1?rq=1).

Comment: @6005 oh thanks. it was really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $B$ is compact so that we know immediately that it is closed and bounded. Moreover, it is totally bounded so for any $\epsilon$ we may find finitely many points of $B$ called $\{y_i\}_{i=1}^N$ such that $B$ is covered by $\epsilon$ balls drawn around $y_i$. Because the collection of the $y_i$ is finite, we may find $M$ such that $\sum_{n=M}^\infty|y_i^n|<\epsilon$ (I use superscripts to denote coordinates) for all $i$. Given any $x\in B$, we may find some $y_i$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty|y_i^n-x^n|<\epsilon$. Applying the triangle inequality, we see that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{M-1}|y_i^n-x^n|+\sum_{n=M}^\infty|x^n|\leq\sum_{n=1}^\infty|y_i^n-x^n|+\sum_{n=M}^\infty|y_i^n|<2\epsilon$$ so that in particular $\sum_{n=M}^\infty|x^n|<2\epsilon$.

Comment: I don't follow the part where you say 'Because the collection of the $y_i$ is finite, we may find $M$ such that...' Can you explain this in more detail?

Comment: For each $y_i$, we may find some $M_i$ for which this is true. We can make $M_i$ bigger and it would still be true. Now since we have finitely many $y_i$, we have finitely many $M_i$. The biggest of these will work.

Answer (score 0):

An idea: If the displayed condition fails, then for some $\epsilon>0,$ no $N$ "works", i.e., for every $N$ there is $x \in B$ such that $\sum_{k=N}^{\infty}|x_n| \ge \epsilon.$ This allows us to choose a sequence $x_k$ in $B$ that satisfies the following: For each $k$ there is $N_k$ such that

$$\sum_{n=N_k}^{\infty}|x_k(n)| \ge \epsilon, \text { and }\sum_{n=N_k}^{\infty}|x_j(n)| < \epsilon/2 \text { for } j=1,\dots, k-1.$$

If I've done this right you'll have $\|x_k-x_j\|_1 \ge \epsilon$ if $j\ne k.$